# Local H2 server + Hibernate: existing database is not visible

Tags: java, hibernate, jdbc, orm, h2

I created a table:

```sql
CREATE TABLE `Category` (
`id`       IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY,
`category` VARCHAR(512) NOT NULL
);
```

And trying to get the data from it, using URL:

```
jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:~/test
```

It works fine from administrator's console.
But "Table "CATEGORY" not found;" occurs during accessing the table with JDBC from mentioned URL.

#### DB properties:

```
jdbc.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:~/test
jdbc.username=sa
jdbc.password=
```

#### Data-source bean.xml:

```xml
 <bean id="dataSource"
      class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
</bean>
```

How fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not quote names manually. Let Hibernate do it for you, just add this property `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true` to quote all database identifiers. It's available in Hibernate since version 3.5.